# A monoid where every element has finitely many divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, notation, noncommutative-algebra, monoid

Is there a special name or has there been any study of monoids of this form? This came up in considering the general construction of a multivariate power series algebra over a ring $R$; usually we take the set of functions $M\to R$ where $M$ is the set $[I]$ of finite multisets on the index set $I$ with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, and define the multiplication as $(ab)_\alpha=\sum_{\beta\le\alpha} a_\beta b_{\alpha-\beta}$, where $\alpha,\beta\in[I]$, $\alpha-\beta$ is the multiset formed by removing all the elements of $\beta$ from $\alpha$ (with multiplicity), and $\beta\le\alpha$ means that all the elements in $\beta$ are in $\alpha$ with equal or greater multiplicity.

This definition makes all the monomials commute with each other, for example if $I=\{1,2\}$ then $x_1^2x_2=x_{\{1,1,2\}}=x_{\{2,1,1\}}=x_2x_1^2$ (where $x_{\{1,1,2\}}$ is notation for the coefficient function that is $1$ at $\{1,1,2\}$ and zero at every other $\alpha\in[I]$). This may not be desirable, so one can generalize to the situation where none of the variables commute, and in this case the monomials are given by strings like $x_1x_2x_1x_3$, which is to say we take $M$ to be the free monoid on $I$, with multiplication now being defined by $(ab)_\alpha=\sum_{\beta\gamma=\alpha} a_\beta b_\gamma$ (where the sum is taken over all possible values of $\beta,\gamma\in M$ such that $\beta\gamma=\alpha$). This is well defined in both the free monoid and the earlier multiset monoid (which is actually the free commutative monoid) because the equation $\beta\gamma=\alpha$ has only finitely many solutions.

So to return to the question, has there been any study or a name for monoids $M$ such that $\{\beta\in M:\beta\mid\alpha\}$ is finite for each $\alpha$, or the power series algebras that result on such monoids (by repeating the above construction on an arbitrary such monoid instead of a free monoid or free commutative monoid)?

Comment: Nice question. Another example is the monoid $(\mathbb{N},\times,1).$

Comment: [Related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411608/what-do-we-call-collections-of-subsets-of-a-monoid-that-satisfy-these-axioms)

Comment: @goblin Wow, it's creepy how similar our questions and thought processes are here. I'd close this as a dupe if your question had an answer.

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Its probably worth saying the obvious thing, namely that if we try to declare that *every* subset of a monoid is "small," then the "cofilter" and "monoid" axioms are automatically satisfied, so we're just left with the "finiteness" axiom, which is of course exactly what you're talking about here.

Comment: @goblin The approach I describe here doesn't generalize to Laurent series, though, and in order to generalize the collection of bounded-below support sets used in the Laurent construction I was also lead to the filter approach, with exactly the axioms you mention in your question.

Comment: That's so cool :)

Comment: There seems to be a connection here to [bornological sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space). If we adjoin to my "cofilter axioms" the requirement that every singleton set be small, or equivalently, that the small sets cover the monoid $M$, then we obtain the definition of a bornological set. My two "monoid axioms" seem to just be saying that the monoid operation is a "bounded map." I haven't checked the details so this might not be quite right. But anyway, this seems to suggest that the finiteness axiom is the only one with any real "teeth" or substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you define division in a monoid $M$ as follows: $v$ divides $u$ if there exist $x, y \in M$ such that $u = xvy$. In semigroup theory, this property is usually denoted $u \leqslant_\mathcal{J} v$ (note the inversion: $v \mid u$ is the same as $u \leqslant_\mathcal{J} v$). The relation $\leqslant_\mathcal{J}$ is one of the [Green's preorders](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yM544W1N2UUC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=Green+preorder+relations&source=bl&ots=7kDIAcnmQp&sig=AHINYKGlQQExOlnFzGJEeox6Jmw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAWoVChMI4NXYsMuryAIVSAoaCh1R3gtk#v=onepage&q=Green%20preorder%20relations&f=false).

A monoid is said to be *finite $\mathcal{J}$-above* if, for each $u \in M$, the set $\{v \in M \mid u \leqslant_\mathcal{J} v\}$ is finite.
I am not sure whether this was the earliest occurrence, but the term appeared in 
[1] and has been used several times in the literature since then.

Formal power series have also be defined on *graded monoids*. See [2].

[1] K. Henckell, S. Lazarus, J. Rhodes, Prime decomposition theorem for arbitrary semigroups: general holonomy decomposition and synthesis theorem. *J. Pure Appl. Algebra* **55** (1988), 127--172.

[2] Sakarovitch, Jacques. Chapter 4: Rational and recognisable power series. *Handbook of weighted automata*, 105--174, Monogr. Theoret. Comput. Sci. EATCS Ser., *Springer, Berlin*, 2009.

Comment: Actually, I define the divides relation so that $v$ divides $u$ if there exists $x$ such that $vx=u$. (It is an asymmetric operation, so you could also call it "left division".) I made a mistake in the above characterization, I thought that $vx=u$ has a unique solution $x$ if it exists, in which case if $u$ has finitely many divisors you could conclude that $vx=u$ has finitely many solutions $(v,x)$ (which is what is needed for the well-definedness of multiplication). In fact such an element $x=u/v$ is uniquely defined in both the free monoid and free comm. monoid, but not in general.

Comment: Then your relation is the Green's preorder $\leqslant_{\mathcal{R}}$...

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I had the same question myself a few weeks ago and wasn't satisfied with any answers I found. Today I stumbled upon the thing I was looking for, so I'm recording it here in case it's useful for others:

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4821) (section 4), such a monoid is called a **finite decomposition monoid**. They call the $R$-algebra that you've described the **total algebra of the monoid $M$ over $R$** and denote it by $R[[M]]$. I'm not sure this terminology is completely standard, but that paper also provides a good supply of other references to look at.

Also, this $R$-algebra construction can be generalized from monoids to categories and the same type of finiteness condition is needed. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0413) for some definitions in this case and a discussion of terminology. The author introduces the term **finely finite category** but indicates that previous literature had used the terminology **'has finite decompositions of degree 2'**.

Lastly, I saw in some places the term 'locally finite' used to refer to this condition (both for monoids and for categories), but this seems ill-advised since 'locally finite semigroup' and 'locally finite category' have alternative meanings which are more common.