# Is there a name for monoids where this set is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid and write its multiplication as $+$. Some monoids have the property that for each $k\in M$ the set $\{(i,j) \in M\times M \mid i + j = k\}$ is finite. Is there a name for this proeprty?

An example is the natural numbers with addition: the set $\{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \mid i + j = k\}$ is finite for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$. A non-example is the reals with addition, or the integers with addition.

As a bonus question, is there a name for monoids where this set is at most countable?

Comment: All your non-examples happen to be groups, which (unless finite) would never have this property due to inverses. Do you have any non-group examples of countably infinite monoids with this property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A monoid where every element has finitely many divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464141/a-monoid-where-every-element-has-finitely-many-divisors) (see "finite decomposition monoid" in the paper of the least-upvoted answer).

Comment: @Mpos sure: take $[0,\infty)$ with addition. (You might also mention that all my examples are commutative - I don't have any non-commutative examples in mind but think the definition still makes sense in that case.)

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist yes, I'd say that counts as a duplicate (although you have to read that question a bit carefully to figure that out). The answer doesn't seem super conclusive but it works for me.